# Using a Set or a List ina composite primary key

Tags: jpa, composite-key

This is about using JPA.
Is it possible I can have a composite primary key and have a set in it
For instance,

```
@Embeddable
class PrimaryKey implements Serializable {
    Set<ParentId> parentId;  //To include both parents
    Integer childId;

//    implement hash and equals
}
```

Here the set of parents(for instance, mother and father) and the child id can uniquely determine a child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that it is not. The spec says about Composite PrimaryKey:

> **2.4.1**
>
> If the dependent entity class has primary key attributes in addition
> to those corresponding to the parent's primary key or if the parent
> has a composite primary key, an embedded id or id class must be used
> to specify the primary key of the dependent entity. It is not
> necessary that parent entity and dependent entity both use embedded
> ids or both use id classes to represent composite primary keys when
> the par- ent has a composite key.

And the definition of PrimaryKey says that:

> **2.4**
>
> A simple primary key or a field or property of a composite primary key
> should be one of the following types: any Java primitive type; any
> primitive wrapper type; java.lang.String; java.util.Date;
> java.sql.Date; java.math.BigDecimal; java.math.BigInte- ger